# Ignore dots in Convert.ToDecimal and return 0

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am using `Convert.ToDecimal` in linq, sometime amount value contains dot (.) as user want to write *.50* or similar, as soon as they enter dot (using Numeric keypad from mobile), code is getting executed and throwing an `exception`.

I am getting `string is not correct format exception` for below code

```
var enteredAmountInTenders = TenderListCollection.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Amount) ? "0" : x.Amount));
```

How can I ignore dot for above code and just get 0?

Comment: Why does it reach the TenderListCollection as string in the first place and then you have a problem converting presumably multiple times when using the data? Sounds more reasonably to do that already in the frontend and only allow a real number type after that.

Comment: What Ralf says. You'll want to do string conversions as far at the leafs as possible (i.e. right after input / right before display).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `decimal.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToDecimal` to cast the value.

```
var enteredAmountInTenders = TenderListCollection
               .Sum(x => !decimal.TryParse(x.Amount,out var result) ? 0 : result);
```

Answer (score -1):

you could check this before your set your property for the object in your `TenderListCollection`.

```
private string _amount = "0";

public string Amount 
{
   get 
   {
       return _amount;
   }

   set 
   {
       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
       {
          if(value != ".")
          {
              _amount = value;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

In general i dont like storing amounts as string, so i also would suggest to rename the Amount to `GivenAmount` and have an Amount Property which is a decimal, this way our code is clean and you dont need to parse in a Lambda expression.

Comment: Having Amount in decimal, problem is - It shows default 0.00 for the all entries. We dont want to show it. We just want to show empty textboxes.